# mobile html5 launch phone's native navigation app

Tags: html, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap/cordova app. Is there a way to open a phone's native navigation app within the browser view? Or is there a best practice on opening native map applications from html5 apps? Or are they all platform specific?

I've read some places that the following works for certain versions of Android

```
<a href="geo:some address here" />Navigate to here</a>
```

and that this works for iOS

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino">Directions</a>
```

I'm amazed that Phonegap hasn't implemented something like this.

Comment: yes you can by writing a plugin, check this link: http://hiediutley.com/2011/04/15/phonegap-tutorial-series-6-writing-your-own-plugin/

Comment: I can confirm that the first link opens a popup to open the navigation app on my android! cheers!

Comment: User the answer of Jeremy Belolo (Angular and Cordova URI whitelisting) and "geo:?q=your query" for andriod and "maps:q=your query" for iOS (or saddr/daddr instead of q for directions)...

Also see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can open the native navigation app on iOS 5 (Google Maps) and iOS 6 (Apple Maps) by using the magic "maps:" protocol, e.g. `window.location = "maps:daddr=50.4,-4.5"`

But to launch the native Google Navigator app on Android you need to use a phonegap plugin. I wrote this one for my own purposes.

**Update**
The plugin has now been updated for Phonegap 3.x and supports Android, iOS and Windows Phone, including an option to prefer Google Maps on iOS.

The plugin is here: https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator

Comment: FWIW for me `maps://?q=` seems to work better than `maps:daddr=` (not sure why the latter does not open the given coordinates, just opens the map app)

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin only works for directions, not just displaying a place on maps... :/ Cool otherwhise

Comment: phonegap-launch-**navigator** == directions. For maps, try a maps plugin e.g. [phonegap-googlemaps-plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin)

Answer (score 7):

The plugin is great! Thanks for sharing!
I tried it in my app but unfortunately I have Phonegap version 3.x and your plugin is only working for Phonegap 2.x :(

So in order to get it working on Phonegap 3.x I got the plugin from your github repo and made some changes so that it works for 3.x

The modified PhoneNavigator Plugin for Phonegap 3.x can be downloaded from my github repo:
https://github.com/viktor0710/PhoneNavigator-Phonegap-3.x.git

How to integrate it in your Phonegap 3.x project:

1. Open a console window
2. Go to your Phonegap app root
3. Then execute: phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/viktor0710/PhoneNavigator-Phonegap-3.x.git
4. Copy "phonenavigator.js" from the repo (www/phonenavigator.js) in your app (ex: yourapp/www)
5. include "phonenavigator.js" in you app:
6. Copy "cordova.js" from the repo (www/cordova.js) in your app (ex: yourapp/www)
7. include "cordova.js" in you app:

How to use it:

```
//function declaration
function navigateTo (lat, lon, successFn, errorFn) {
    cordova.require('cordova/plugin/phonenavigator').doNavigate(lat, lon, successFn, errorFn);
}

//set lat and lon variables. Most probably read them from the UI
var latitude =  48.137607;
var longitude = 11.568569;

//call function
navigateTo(
    latitude,
    longitude,
    function(){
        console.log("Successfully opened navigator");
    },
    function(){
        console.log("Error opening navigator");
    }
);
```

Comment: I've finally updated the original plugin to support Phonegap 3.x, along with adding support for setting the destination by place name as well as lat/lon: https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator. There's now also an example project for Android and iOS: https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator-example

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned above, the following works on Galaxy S4 Android (just tested it), to bring up the Google Maps/Navigation app and waze:

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35">Wikimedia Headquarters</a>
```

Credit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI#Example

Please also see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19765368/2728686

Comment: On iPad it opens google earth, on android google maps.

Comment: @IhorDIM Yeah, if the iPad does not have another app installed (like Waze or a GPS software) to handle geo:uri requests, then it may revert to Google Earth. Android should always use Google Maps or offer an option between Google Maps, other software and Google Earth. I haven't tested on any iOS devices yet, but would be interesting to see how iOS7 iPhone handles the geo:uri standard.

Answer (score 7):

For the record, if someone find this thread by looking on Google like I did, it worked for me directly, working with Ionic framework, by doing two things :

- In the myapp.config(...) of your app add

  ```
  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|geo):/);
  ```

  (dont forget to add $compileProvider as a dependency)
- In the config.xml, add the line

  ```
  <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  ```

That's all.

Comment: Good answer! with this you don't need any plugin to make this work.

Comment: Good and nearly complete answer! But one have to mention to use "geo:?q=your query" in order to pass a query to the (google) maps on andriod and "maps:q=your query" for iOS (or saddr/daddr instead of q for directions)...
Also see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Answer (score 2):

Cordova 3.6.0 introduces a second whitelist, for restricting which URLs are allowed to launch external applications. In previous versions of Cordova, all non-http URLs, such as mailto:, geo:, sms: and intent, were implicitly allowed to be the target of an a tag. Because of the potential for an application to leak information, if an XSS vulnerability allows an attacker to construct arbitrary links, these URLs must be whitelisted as well, starting in Cordova 3.6.0.

[Cordova 3.6.0 Whitelist Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)

So you need to add explicitly in the config.xml:

```
  <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
  <access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Comment: And for Angulars URL sanitation: $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|tel|mailto|geo|.....):/);