# Google Navigation Intent via Phonegap

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, navigation, cordova, phonegap-plugins

For my application (in phonegap) i would like to create a button that **links directly to the Google Navigation App with a certain address.**

Do anybody knows how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to do the same thing so I wrote a plugin to do it - you can find the source code [on my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286951/mobile-html5-launch-phones-native-navigation-app/17255604#17255604). At the bottom is a link to my Eclipse project with a test case :-)

Comment: We are encountering the following error: Console.log prints "Error opening navigator". We don't use Cordova web view and we don't use native android classes

Comment: Download my Eclipse test project [from here](http://ge.tt/7CdZG3k/v/0) to see an example of how to use the plugin. Check the LogCat output for your project in Eclipse to see if a Java exception occurred when calling the plugin.

Answer (score 4):

You can just fire a new Intent with the following adress and user will be asked to choose Google Maps or not?

"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+lat+","+lng

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017:

- `"https://maps.google.com/?q=loc:" ++ lat ++ "," ++ lng`
- Add `<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />` to config.xml