# "Directions Not Available" Bring up navigation app in ios

Tags: android, html, ios, navigation, apple-maps

We are trying to bring up the **navigation app** using HTML Code. We could make it happen in Android without any issues taking guidance from [mobile html5 launch phone's native navigation app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14286951/1904479) for iphone, [Google navigation on a html5 Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9819006/1904479) for android devices. It works quite for android devices. Tested in Sony Experia, Moto-G all is well.

But, when it comes to iphone, i get a mixed response. An Error Message saying:

> "A route cannot be determined from this start location"

**I tried out thie following code:** 
`<a href="maps:daddr=10.009465, 76.366485&saddr=9.948264, 76.294044" class="sml-txt">driving<br>directions</a>`
**And got the following response in iphone 5, using iOS 7.1.1**
[image]

**But it works quite well for the ipad we tested in using the iOS 5.1.1. Still can't get a way to work it out in iphone with ios 7 or above versions.**
Any idea or a way in which this can be overcome?
We shall be glad to have help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wandered around for the reason for the same. Then found that for places in India the apple maps doesn't seem to have the database for the same. Well finding directions from my home to office itself it point out the same error saying that the "Directions (are) not available".